# SQL table named with reserved keyword in Excel

Tags: sql, excel, keyword, reserved

I have the following code I would like to put into Excel:

```
SELECT Trans.TransactionNumber, Trans.CustomerID, Trans.Total, TrE.ItemID, TrE.Quantity,     TeE.Description
FROM "Transaction" AS Trans
JOIN TransactionEntry AS TrE
ON Trans.TransactionNumber = TrE.TransactionNumber
JOIN TenderEntry AS TeE
ON Trans.TransactionNumber = TeE.TransactionNumber
```

The problem is that whoever created the DB named one of the tables as Transaction. I can access it SQL itself with double quotes. But every time I try in Excel (either w/ double quotes or square brackets) it tells me "Could not add the table Transaction."

Is there a way around the keyword issue in Excel?

Comment: have you tried using `[Transaction]`?

Comment: I believe the above comment will work, but have you also considered placing that select statement within a sub query?

Comment: I have used the square brackets but it gives me the same error. I'll look at the sub-query.

Comment: It works now with the double quotes. Not sure why. Thanks for the help.